Trying to get javascript variables on one php page to show in another using WYSIWYG Web Builder 19
I have a javascript in the head of the index page and this function stores the variables from the functions in localstorage:
<script type="text/javascript">

function storeGlobals() {

localstorage.setItem("name", name.value)
localstorage.setItem("current_age", current_age.value)
localstorage.setItem("retirement_age", retirement_age.value)
localstorage.setItem("base_salary", base_salary.value)
localstorage.setItem("emailid", emailid.value)

localstorage.setItem("FEGLI_BASIC_LIFETIME_COST", "$"+total_FEGLI_BASIC_LIFETIME_COST)
localstorage.setItem("fegli_opa_cost", "$"+total_fegli_opa_cost)
localstorage.setItem("UB_PERMANENT_LIFETIME_COST", "$"+total_UB_PERMANENT_LIFETIME_COST)
localstorage.setItem("fegli_opb_cost", "$"+total_fegli_opb_cost)
localstorage.setItem("UB_TERM_COST", "$"+total_UB_TERM_COST)
localstorage.setItem("Estimated_Total_FEGLI_Lifetime_Cost", "$"+total_Estimated_Total_FEGLI_Lifetime_Cost)

localstorage.setItem("total_savings", "$"+total_savings_final)
localstorage.setItem("regular_finalresult", "$"+regular_total_savings_final)
localstorage.setItem("regular_fegli_basic_coverage", "$"+FEGLI_BASIC_COVERAGE_AMT_report_final)
localstorage.setItem("regular_fegli_opa", "$"+FEGLI_OPA_AMT_report_final)
localstorage.setItem("regular_fegli_opb", "$"+"$"+FEGLI_OPB_AMT_report_final)

}
</script>

Then, in another page (results.php) I have the following in the head tags:
<script type="text/javascript">

function readGlobals() {

localstorage.getItem("name")
localstorage.getItem("current_age")
localstorage.getItem("retirement_age")
localstorage.getItem("base_salary")
localstorage.getItem("emailid")

localstorage.getItem("FEGLI_BASIC_LIFETIME_COST")
localstorage.getItem("fegli_opa_cost")
localstorage.getItem("UB_PERMANENT_LIFETIME_COST")
localstorage.getItem("fegli_opb_cost")
localstorage.getItem("UB_TERM_COST")
localstorage.getItem("Estimated_Total_FEGLI_Lifetime_Cost")

localstorage.getItem("total_savings")
localstorage.getItem("regular_finalresult")
localstorage.getItem("regular_fegli_basic_coverage")
localstorage.getItem("regular_fegli_opa")
localstorage.getItem("regular_fegli_opb")

}
</script>

I am calling this function as a onload event.
Does this look correct? So far, it's not working. If you are familiar with WYSIWYG Web Builder, what would be the correct way to do this. Any help is appreciated.
Update
I tried one variable and I still cannot get it to work:
<script type="text/javascript">

function readGlobals() {

if document.getElementById("age").value = "13" {
document.getElementById("age").value = "55 through 59";
}

const total_savings = localStorage.getItem("total_savings");
document.getElementById("total_savings").value = total_savings;

}

</script>


You're not assigning the values of the getItem calls into any variables. So nothing will happen when you run that code, and you won't be able to use the values. It's not working because you're not using any of the data you're retrieving from the storage. Where exactly were you expecting to be able to use the data in your results.php page? Had you written any code to try and use the values? I cannot determine how you decided it wasn't working. It's simply incomplete, that's all.

Review the basic examples in the documentation, and also make sure, at the fundamental level, that you understand the concept of assiging a value to a variable when writing code.

this is just plain JavaScript, I can't see anything related to any web builder in your code.  It doesn't seem to be relevant. Anyway...do you ever check your browser's Console for JS errors? That's the most basic first debugging step when you have a problem with some JS code. You should have at least one error. For one thing, JS variables are case-sensitive. localstorage needs to be localStorage (as per the documentation link I gave you above - did you read it?). A basic demo shows that if you correct the case issue, the code should work: https://jsfiddle.net/bqmvscfu/

P.S. As an aside, if you are using some kind of web builder tool, surely the whole point of such a thing is that you don't need to bother writing this kind of low-level code...are you sure there's no feature in the tool already which lets you pass variables between pages? It's pretty standard web functionality

P.S. if document.getElementById("age").value = "13" { document.getElementById("age").value = "55 through 59"; } also contains both syntax and logic errors (missing brackets round the condition, and use of assignment = in the condition instead of comparison ==), and it's unclear what the point of it is (if someone is 13 they're clearly not 55!) - or why you included it here since it has nothing to do with the storage values issue. A corrected version would be if (document.getElementById("age").value == "13") { document.getElementById("age").value = "55 through 59"; } though.

you can't call php variable directly in javascript instead, try the below approach to set the value and get it back based on your already written code
using  or 


<script type="text/javascript">

function storeGlobals() {

localstorage.setItem("name", name.value)
localstorage.setItem("current_age", current_age.value)
localstorage.setItem("retirement_age", retirement_age.value)
localstorage.setItem("base_salary", base_salary.value)
localstorage.setItem("emailid", emailid.value)

localstorage.setItem("FEGLI_BASIC_LIFETIME_COST", <?php echo  $total_FEGLI_BASIC_LIFETIME_COST ?>)
localstorage.setItem("fegli_opa_cost",  <?php echo  $total_fegli_opa_cost ?>)
localstorage.setItem("UB_PERMANENT_LIFETIME_COST",  <?php echo $total_UB_PERMANENT_LIFETIME_COST ?>)
localstorage.setItem("fegli_opb_cost",  <?php echo $total_fegli_opb_cost ?>)
localstorage.setItem("UB_TERM_COST",  <?php echo $total_UB_TERM_COST ?>)
localstorage.setItem("Estimated_Total_FEGLI_Lifetime_Cost",  <?php echo $total_Estimated_Total_FEGLI_Lifetime_Cost ?>)

localstorage.setItem("total_savings",  <?php echo $total_savings_final ?>)
localstorage.setItem("regular_finalresult",  <?php echo $regular_total_savings_final ?>)
localstorage.setItem("regular_fegli_basic_coverage",  <?php echo $FEGLI_BASIC_COVERAGE_AMT_report_final ?>)
localstorage.setItem("regular_fegli_opa",  <?php echo $FEGLI_OPA_AMT_report_final ?>)
localstorage.setItem("regular_fegli_opb",  <?php echo $FEGLI_OPB_AMT_report_final ?>)

}
</script>




I don't think the OP is trying to use PHP variables in their code - looking at the variable names, I think they're just trying to store JS values and put a dollar sign $ at the start of the string. But I could be wrong. The more significant issue is that they think it's not working because they aren't actually retrieving the values properly when the results page loads - see my comment under the question.

That is correct. I am not using PHP because the software (WYSIWYG Web Builder) does not allow Javascript and Php in the same script. How do I add the "$" and variables together and assign them to a variable that I can then load on another page?

@rubidex Exactly how you're doing it now except that, as I said above, when you retrieve the values from storage you need to assign them to a variable so you can actually use them in your code, or at the very least you need to set them as the content of a html element in the page

I posted one variable above (as an answer unfortunately) and I still cannot get it to work. @ADyson - Do you have experience with WYSIWYG Web Builder?
